# Increase of standard error with the increase of number of parameters

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

Suppose in a multiple regression setup we somehow know the true regressors. My prof. said that in that case if we add some more regressors (either correlated or uncorrelated with the previous ones) then the standard error will increase. Can you please guide me that why is it so?
 Any hint or insights will be very helpful.

Comment: Please explain what a "jargon regressor" means.

Comment: Jargon means we know the true regressors but we add some extra unnecessary regressors

Comment: I voted to reopen this question, even though it is unclear what the standard error applies to (maybe the standard error of parameter estimates?), because regardless of how one interprets "standard error," such a broad claim is obviously false.  Proof: adjoin the residuals to the set of regressors. The new fit is perfect, with $R^2=1$ and zero for all standard errors of the parameter estimates.  This indicates the meaning of "know the true regressors" needs to be carefully stated.  "Will increase" needs clarification, too, because adding more regressors may *accidentally* improve the results.

Comment: Thanks for raising such points. I haven't thought of such implications so surely the question needs careful clarifications. In the meantime, I have to go back and think over these points.